# Check string to see if it is a palindrome of any of it's permutations

Tags: python, time-complexity

I've created a function that does this successfully(I'm pretty sure), but I'm worried about the efficiency in part of it.  I have two nested `for` loops that I think make this algorithm's worst case around O(n^2).  Is there any way I can improve this?

```
def palindrome(string):
    s = [c.replace(' ', '') for c in string]
    merged = "".join(s)
    srt = sorted(merged)
    dic = {}
    singles = 0

    for i in srt:
        if i not in dic:
            dic[i] = 1
        else:
            # Worried about this second loop having to run for every i in srt
            for key, value in dic.items():
                if key == i:
                    dic[key] = 2 
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if value == 1:
            singles += 1
    if singles > 1:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: what does "palindrome of any of its permutations" mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for [codereview.se]

Comment: It tests if any permutation of the letters in the string could be a palindrome.

Comment: Doesn't need to be an actual word, just a palindrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to find out if there is at most one "single" letter (and others are paired). Thus we count the letters with `collections.Counter` and ensure that only 0 or 1 of them has odd count:

```
from collections import Counter


def has_palindrome(string):
    return sum(v % 2 for v in Counter(string).values()) <= 1

print(has_palindrome('abcabcc'))  # True
print(has_palindrome('abc'))  # False
```

Answer (score 1):

As it tests if any permutation of the letters in the string could be a palindrome.

I would suggest:

```
from collections import Counter

def palindrome(string):
    s = string.replace(' ', '')
    return not sum(v % 2 == 1 for k,v in Counter(string)) > 1
```

This checks of the sum of the number of counts of character occurrences that are odd is not greater than one.

Answer (score 0):

Above code will fail if there are three occurrences of certain character. Try `abcabccddd`

Slight modification to fix the issue:

```
def checkPalindromPermutation(word):
    values = collections.Counter(word).values()
    if sum((v % 2) for v in values) > 1 or any(v > 2 for v in values):
        return False
    return True
```